# find a method sort NSArray on obj-C what equivalent python sort (timsort)

Tags: python, objective-c, sorting

The python server api will check the request signature, and the mechanism is get all values, and sort, then append a secret and md5 hash. But I don't know how to simulate the sort() function in obj-C. There's the python make_sign code:

```
def make_sign(api_secret, params=[]):
"""
    >>> make_sign("mysecret",[1,'2','string'])
    'AACF0E5427EECA3490C5642C9916785'
"""
_params = [p for p in params if p is not None]
_params.sort()
_params.insert(0, api_secret)
strs = ''.join(_params)
mds = md5(strs.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
return mds.upper()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort an instance of `NSArray` with the [`-sortedArray…` methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW12). This starts from simple sorting on a key (for the object itself use `self`) up to sort functions and closures. Just pick a method!

However, sorting strings is not that unambiguously it might be. I. e. in German there are different ways to sort "A" and "Ä" or "s", "ss" and  "ß". So to have an identical sort order, you maybe have to use `-sortedArrayUsingComparator:` and write your own comparison.

Comment: I known about `-sortedArray`, but don't know how to compare the NSArray both contains figure and character and string.

Comment: You can check for a type with `-isKindOfClass:`. Are all data of the type `NSString`? However, in such a case you have to do as described in the second paragraph, because there is no natural order. Maybe this is a starting point: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare:options: